# Explanation for a few running services in google play service

Tags: google-play-services

Can someone explain what...PlaceDetectionAsyncService is?  I found in developer options, running services,  google play services. I wanted to know if it was just a location provider..etc also
DeviceConnectionWatcher? What are these and what are they used for?

Comment: Play Services aren't open source, those are Google's proprietary stuff. They provide developers APIs to achieve certain tasks but how the Play Services achieve those tasks isn't publicly known. Apps use PlayDetection APIs to ask for current location of the device. DeviceConnection APIs are what Google named Nearby Connections.

Comment: So if i have locations on I would have the same thing running in my apps?

Comment: "Play Services aren't open source" means that Google doesn't wants to let us know which services are meant for which purpose. There are a number of services related to location including `network.NetworkLocationService`, `internal.server.HardwareArProviderService`, `geofencer.service.GeofenceProviderService`, `geocode.GeocodeService`, `fused.FusedLocationService`, `internal.server.GoogleLocationService` and `internal.GoogleLocationManagerService`. If you ask me what each of these services does, I won't be able to answer. You may try by disabling them one by one to see what happens.